# Flutter API Change Issue

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-web

I have to change Search API Url in this search function,

```
Future<List<Product>> searchProducts({
    name,
    categoryId = '',
    tag = '',
    attribute = '',
    attributeId = '',
    page,
    lang,
    listingLocation = '',
    userId,
  }) async {
    try {
      var endPoint = 'products?status=publish&page=$page&per_page=$ApiPageSize';

      if ((lang?.isNotEmpty ?? false) && kAdvanceConfig['isMultiLanguages']) {
        endPoint += '&lang=$lang';
      }

      if (categoryId != null) {
        endPoint += '&category=$categoryId';
      }

      if (attribute != null) {
        endPoint += '&attribute=$attribute';
      }

      if (attributeId != null) {
        endPoint += '&attribute_term=$attributeId';
      }

      if (tag != null) {
        endPoint += '&tag=$tag';
      }
      if (userId != null) {
        endPoint += '&user_id=$userId';
      }
      var response = await wcApi.getAsync('$endPoint&search=$name');
      if (response is Map && isNotBlank(response['message'])) {
        throw Exception(response['message']);
      } else {
        var list = <Product>[];
        for (var item in response) {
          if (!kAdvanceConfig['hideOutOfStock'] || item['in_stock']) {
            list.add(jsonParser(item));
          }
        }
```

The API URL I need to put instead of endpoint is

```
website.com/wp-json/app/v2/gws_site_search_custom?gws_search=search-term
```

I tried changing it this way

```
 Future<List<Product>> searchProducts({
    name,
  }) async {
    try {
      var guaven = 'wp-json/app/v2/gws_site_search_custom';
      var response = '$guaven?gws_search=$name';
      if (response is Map && isNotBlank(response['message'])) {
        throw Exception(response['message']);
      } else {
        var list = <Product>[];
        for (var item in response) {
          if (!kAdvanceConfig['hideOutOfStock'] || item['in_stock']) {
            list.add(jsonParser(item));
          }
        }
```

But it gave me errors

*
lib/frameworks/woocommerce/services/woo_commerce.dart:721:50: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
if (response is Map && isNotBlank(response['message'])) {
^
lib/frameworks/woocommerce/services/woo_commerce.dart:725:26: Error: The type 'String' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable'.

- 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
  for (var item in response) {
  ^
  lib/frameworks/woocommerce/services/woo_commerce.dart:734:49: Error: The getter 'endPoint' isn't defined for the class 'WooCommerce'.
  ^^^^^^^^

- 

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you add the response json?